# Перегрузка оператора =

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
 Accumulator & Accumulator::operator=(const char* right){
    material = right;
    return *this;
}
```

В общем есть такой код перегрузки оператора в классе нужно что бы оператор при присваивании менял значение поля материал. Код вроде верно написал но пишет ошибку мол не понимаю я как это делать при вот таком коде:

```
Accumulator *kek = new Accumulator(true,12.1,11.1, 5000, "Li-On");
kek = "Ba-On";
```

Текст ошибки: (среда VS professional 2017)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я что то не дописал что бы компилятор заметил этот код? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы хотите вызвать оператор присваивания для *указателя*, а не для объекта.

Попробуйте

```
*kek = "Ba-On";
```

Но мне не нравится сам ваш принцип - хранить указатель на строку... А если вы передадите адрес какого-то массива, а он потом будет перезаписан?

Comment: Не я думаю вариант с массивом это велосипед, может  проблема в том что я пытаюсь вернуть указатель?

Comment: Да ты был прав просто использование указателя решило проблему